# Finding the input element of next TD

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors

having trouble finding the `input` element in the next `td`. I need to get place a value into the td class of tblCashSum's textbox.

However, if I do the following:

```
alert(formElement.nextAll('td.tblCashSum').find('input.cashSum').val());
```

It reads undefined.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class='tblCashType'>100</td>
    <td class='tblCashAmount'><asp:TextBox class="inputBox" ID="noteAmount100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class='tblCashSum'><asp:TextBox class="inputBoxDisabled cashSum" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" ID="cashSum100"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
```

Jquery:

```
$("noteAmount").blur(function(){
 calc($(this));
});

function calc(formElement)
{
    a = formElement.val();
    b = formElement.closest('td').siblings('td.tblCashType').text();
    x = a * b;
    formElement.nextAll('td.tblCashSum').find('input.cashSum').val(x);
}
```

Comment: is `$("noteAmount")` correct? -- is `calc($(this).val());` correct? or is it supposed to be `calc($(this));`

Comment: yeah, i made a mistake there, but the function calc is still not working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a string which is the value of the input element, you should first pass the object instead, note that you have missed the `#` for the ID selector.

```
$("#noteAmount").blur(function(){
     calc($(this));
});
```

Then you can use `parent` and `next` methods:

```
function calc($formElement) {
    a = parseInt($formElement.val(), 10);
    b = parseInt($formElement.closest('td').siblings('td.tblCashType').text(), 10);
    x = a * b;
    $formElement.parent().next().find('input.cashSum').val(x);
}
```

Please note that if your elements have ID attributes you can select them directly which is faster than traversing the DOM.

---

I can't find an element with ID of *noteAmount* in your markup, if you have multiple elements with the same IDs your markup becomes invalid and you will get unexpected results , you can also try the following:

```
$('.inputBox').blur(function(){
    a = this.value
    $this = $(this);
    b = $this.parent().prev().text();
    x = parseInt(a, 10) * parseInt(b, 10);
    $this.parent().next().find('input.cashSum').val(x);
});
```

Comment: I like `$formElement` naming scheme for jQuery objects.

Comment: I made a mistake, I do only pass the object and not the value. I have changed the question. sorry

Comment: Niceone undefined. I will incorporate the parseInt also, very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.next()` on the `.parent()`  of input

Try `formElement.closest('td').next('td.tblCashSum')`

OR

```
formElement.parent().next('td.tblCashSum')
```

//

Also `$("noteAmount")` does not make any sense ... 
Supposed to be  `$('[id*="noteAmount"]')`

```
$('[id*="noteAmount"]').blur(function(){
 calc($(this));
});

function calc(formElement)
{
    a = formElement.val();
    b = formElement.closest('td').siblings('td.tblCashType').text();
    x = a * b;
    formElement.closest('td').next('td.tblCashSum').find('input.cashSum').val(x);
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake, I do only pass the object and not the value. I have changed the question. sorry

Comment: You need to use .next() on the .parent() of input